# Restricting the resizing of Div

Tags: css

I want to restrict the resizing of div outside the pdf. what do I have to do to achieve that? I want that div should not resize ouside of pdf or we can say input-form selector here.

```
<div [id]="controlId"  height="70px" width="220px" [ngStyle]="dragControlCSS" class="image" cdkDragBoundary=".input-form" cdkDrag
 (cdkDragEnded)="dragImageControl($event,controlId)" #drag="cdkDrag"
 (resized)="onResized()"
 >
  <img
  [src]="profile"
  style="height:-webkit-fill-available; width:-webkit-fill-available;" top="0" cdkDragHandle
   >
   <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="remove-button" (click) ="removeImageControl(controlId)">
    <mat-icon style="color: #bab5b5">close</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
```

```
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  // padding: 2px 6px 3px;
  border: 3px dotted #ee9090;
  // background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  background-color: transparent;
  // cursor: ns-resize;
    overflow: hidden;
    // resize: both;

    // max-height: 1.5%;
    // min-height: 54px;
    // max-width: 40%;
    // min-width: 12%;
    // width: 106px;
    // height: 60px;
  }
.input-form {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;


  //overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 6%;`your text`
  & input {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    // border: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem, preferably as a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), or as a CodeSandbox link or similar.  In its present form, your code isn't vanilla CSS/HTML, and most people will not want to spin up a new VSCode project to try to answer this question.

Comment: If your JS event handlers are important to the question, you should include your JS as well please.  I will also mention that I don't think I see anything related to a PDF in your code, and since that seems to be an important part of the question, it will be good to include this as well.